# Как установить сканер МФУ SCX 4100 в Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, установка, железо

Подключаю МФУ Samsung SCX-4100 через USB принтер на Ubuntu 12.04. Подхватывается автоматом. сканер не работает. Скачивал драйвер с официального сайта, просматривал форумы пробовал и пытался... В итоге три переустановки системы, но сканер молчит. Верю, что есть некий способ, но плясать с бубном сил моих больше нет. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Если ещё для кого то этот вопрос актуален ставьте палец вверх, так на него быстрее ответят.

Comment: quiteinsane установил отсюда http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/quiteinsane/downloadЧто с этим делать всёравно не понятно http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-SAMSUNG пока не работает

Comment: осталось только> sudo apt-get install sane sane-utils

Comment: извиняюсь за недостаточную информативность ответа, но и это я тоже сделал.  quiteinsane запустил через SUDO он написал "No devices were found" и запустился с пустым окном (нет списка оборудования)потом просто запустил, он написал "Could not lock file.quiteinsane will not work without this file. Please ensure, that there's enough space on your harddisk and that you have write permission for the directory. QuiteInsaneFolder in your home directory." и не запустился.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установил с нуля Ubuntu 12.0.4 и установил все обновления.
Команда:

```
lsusb
```

показала:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04e8:3413 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd SCX-4100 Scanner
```

Написал команду:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

Добавил в текст открытого файла:

```
#Samsung SCX-4100    
usb 0x04e8 0x3413
```

Перезагружаю компьютер. Скачал все драйвера для linux с [сайта для похожего устройства](http://www.samsung.com/ru/support/model/SCX-4828FN/XEV), ещё [тут](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-scx-4828-laser-multifunction-printer-series/17157038), и [тут](https://yadi.sk/d/ktWsm67jchz8W) ,разархивировал в домашнюю директорию: `PSU_1.00.tar.gz` Команда:

```
sudo cdroot/Linux/psu/install.sh
```

разархивировал в домашнюю директорию: `ULD_Linux_V1.00.06.tar.gz` Команда:     `sudo uld/install.sh`
со всем соглашаюсь. Команда:

```
sudo scanimage -L
```

Показала:

```
device `smfp:usb;04E8;3413;8J66BABYC14766K.' is a SAMSUNG SCX-4100 Series on USB Scannerxsane
```

xsane запустилась и произвела сканирование.Всем успехов в поиске решения проблем!

**Все действия:**

установил:

```
sane sane-utilsxsane
```

Команда:

```
sudo sane-find-scanner -q
```

показала:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x093a, product=0x2476) at libusb:003:002
```

Команда:

```
sudo scanimage -L
```

показала:

```
No scanners were identified
```

(и ещё много чего, в конце отправила меня на FAQ)
На сайте sane-project.org нашёл свою модель сканера перешёл на страницу: sane-project.org/sane-epson2.5.htmlВ разделе "NAME" обнаружил: "sane-epson2" в поиске нарвался на страницу: manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/sane-epson2.5.html Deb пакет не встал, поругавшись на зависимость, скачал sane-epson2.5.gz

Написал команду:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

Добавил в текст открытого файла:

```
#Epson SCX 4100
usb 0x093a 0x2476
```

Переместил разархивированный sane-epson2.5.gz в папку /etc/sane.d переименовал в sane-epson2.5.conf и назначил права 777 Перезагружаю компьютер.

Обнаружил, что МФУ у меня Samsung

Нашёл сайт: www.kreont.name/ubuntu/samsung-scx-4100-ubuntu.html

В терминале:

```
wget -O - http://www.bchemenet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sane samsungmfp-scanner
```

но пакет samsungmfp-scanner небыл найден

ввёл следующее:

```
echo "blacklist usblp" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-usblp.confsudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool autotools-dev dpkg-dev fakeroot patch libusb-dev build-essential
```

В домашней директории:

```
mk sane
```

файл sane-epson2.5.conf переместил в созданную только что "sane" и переименовал в sane-epson2.5.patch

Обнаружил, что usb устройство было вебкамерой, изьял её.

Написал команду:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

Убрал из текста открытого файла:

```
#Epson SCX 4100
usb 0x093a 0x2476
```

Далее см. в начале.

**Всем кому помогло голосуйте за ответ! Мне будет очень приятно!**

Comment: скачать драйверы https://yadi.sk/d/ktWsm67jchz8W

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a regression bug in ubuntu 12.04.I filled this bug report:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-frontends/+bug/1026159

Answer (score 1):

Пакеты для работы со сканерами установлены? [Sane](http://www.sane-project.org/) и соответственно графический фронтэнд Xsane?

Comment: был установлен simple scan. установил xsane - не помогло.http://www.sane-project.org/ - не разобрался

Comment: ~$ sudo scanimage[sudo] password for alexandr: scanimage: no SANE devices found

Comment: ~$ sane-find-scanner  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

Comment: //продолжение   # Not checking for parallel port scanners.  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports  # can't be detected by this program.  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as  # necessary.

Comment: Что говорит lsusb?