# Как переподключать сканер после каждой операции сканирования linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Имеется ubuntu 17.04 x64, МФУ Samsung scx-4100
Устанавливал и использовал [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/342338/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%9C%D0%A4%D0%A3-scx-4100-%D0%B2-ubuntu-12-04). 
Сканирует только после переподключения устройства, иначе пишет ошибку ввода-вывода.

Comment: А если sane через systemctl перезапускать?

Comment: @donRumata пример команды можно?

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart saned`. Я не помню как точно называется сервис sane.

Comment: Обновитесь до последних пакетов, поищите баг на убунтовской багзилле, если нет, создайте!